# How to identify html tags in html string

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have below html string, where i am trying to identify the `<br>` tag start and end of the whole text inside an html string using the below code

```
 var htmlstring = "<p><span><br> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>"
 var document = new HtmlDocument();
 document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
           
 var nodes= rootNode.SelectNodes("//br")
```

but it is giving all `<br>` tags nodes where i want only at the start and at the end of whole html text string in below html string

```
<p><span><br> text <b> text&nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>
```

I am looking for nodes should be 2 instead of 3 but getting as 3 as it counts the `<br>` tag  presented in between text as well.

Could any one please help on this how can i achieve this, many thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use linq: `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br").First()`?

Comment: You should have a definition for a text node, what is a text node? for example <p> tags are considered as text node

Comment: @FlatEric this will give the count for this one as well `<p><span> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text</span></p>` and i don't want that one i just want to identify the tags only at the start and at the end in whole html string, basically looking to remove the tags later

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani i just want to pick only the tags`<br>` at the start or at the end of whole html string that is what i am looking for, but above code is giving all the tags

Comment: I don't know why `First` should give you anything but the first...

Comment: @FlatEric, In this case it will pickup this one as well right the`<br>` tag in between text and i don't want that to picked up `<p><span> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text</span></p>`

Comment: I am looking for the nodes(`<br>`) tags which are at the start and at the end of whole html string to remove those one later and if there are in the middle of string I need to leave those as it is in a string

Comment: What are the rules for the boundaries? Is it always a `span`?

Comment: sorry span is also not a mandatory tag here.

Comment: @FlatEric span might not present some times as well in some conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split` method to solve your problem. I have a suggestion for you as follows. It prints text between `<br>` tags which are start and end tags. In addition, you can modify the output according to your requirements. Maybe it can be solved by using the *regex pattern*.

```
const string tag = "<br>";
var splitedHtmlString = htmlString.Split(tag);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < splitedHtmlString.Length - 1; i++)
{
     builder.Append(splitedHtmlString[i]);
     builder.Append(tag);
}
builder.Remove(builder.ToString().Length - tag.Length, tag.Length);
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Output: `text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text`

Comment: sorry it is removing `<p>` tags as well at the start and at the end and getting an error for this one `<p><span></span> text <b>&nbsp;<br></b>text </span></p>`  and the error is `StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')`

Comment: @EnigmaState You can start the for loop from the zeroth index so you can get <p> tags.

Comment: for this input`<p><span> text <b>&nbsp;<br></b>text </span></p>` getting output as `<p><span> text <b>&nbsp;` instead of `<p><span> text <b>&nbsp;<br></b>text </span></p>`

Comment: @EnigmaState Hmm ok, just write the for loop like : `for (int i = 0; i < splitedHtmlString.Length ; i++)`

Comment: sorry to bother you again, In this case `<p><span><br> text <b>&nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>` is not removing the start and end tags and output is same as input and looking for this kind of output `<p><span>text <b>&nbsp;<br></b>text </span></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to an HtmlDocument and filter by nodes, using HtmlAgilityPack library

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();

document.LoadHtml("your html code");

var htmlTag = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br");